# Returning an Optional as another type in Java (unboxing)

Tags: java, option-type

Sometimes I have to return some "Object" (not an Optional, to maintain backwards compatibility) in a method and the return value is an Optional.

This example seems to work (it compiles and doesn't give an error), but I don't feel comfortable with this. Can someone explain why this works and conforms that this is correct?

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        String result = main.WorkingWithOptional();
        // yes, I know, an Optional here would be better and cleaner.
        if (result != null)
            System.out.println(result);
        else
            System.out.println("RESULT IS NULL");
    }

    public String WorkingWithOptional() {
        Optional<String> res = Optional.of("Test");

        return res.orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: "explain why this works" -- what do you mean? What makes you think it should not work?

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes. Care to explain why?

Comment: The return value of your method is `String`, not `Optional`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic So is this casting or unboxing? Could you point me to documentation that explains this?

Comment: Neither. [`Optional.orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) is a generic method that will return you a variable that has the type of the Optional, `String` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did read the documentation, but overlooked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at java doc [Optional#orElse(T other)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)

> Return the value if present, otherwise return other

in your case

```
 Optional<String> res = Optional.of("Test");
```

`res.get()` or `res.orElse()` will always return `"Test"` String.
You can think of an `Optional` as sort of a wrapper for your value. It might contain the value or it might not.

```
Optional op = Optional.ofNullable(null); // empty
System.out.println(op.orElse("default value")); // "default value"
op.get();// will produce NoSuchElementException, becase it is empty
```

Answer (score 2):

How `orElse` works is that it takes a default value to be returned if the `Optional` is empty. If the `Optional` is not empty, the value it contains is returned.

In this case the default value you use is `null`. It could have been any `String` e.g. `"NOT FOUND"`.